C++ connection to Sage 300 problems
I am creating a c++ app that collects a connection string and query from a file and the connects to a database and runs the query and packages the results but i am having and issue with Sage 300 but no matter what i do with the connection string it won't connect. please take a look and let me know if i missed something
Error: Error connecting to the database.

ConnectionString: DSN={CP TIMBERLINE};uid=<User>;pwd=<Password>;
Query: SELECT * from JCM_MASTER__JOB_1

Here is my code:
   std::ifstream file(filePath);
  if (!file.is_open()) {
      std::ofstream errorFile("Resultsfor_Error.csv", std::ios_base::app);
      errorFile << "Error opening file: " << filePath << std::endl;
      return;
  }

  std::cout << "processPriorityFile Started for " + filePath;

  ThreadData data;
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
      if (line.find("Thread_ID:") != std::string::npos) {
          data.threadID = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find(":") + 1));
      }
      else if (line.find("Connectionstring:") != std::string::npos) {
          data.connectionString = line.substr(line.find(":") + 1);
      }
      else if (line.find("Query:") != std::string::npos) {
          data.query = line.substr(line.find(":") + 1);
      }
  }

  std::ofstream outputFile("Resultsfor_" + std::to_string(data.threadID) + ".csv", std::ios_base::app);
  if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
      std::ofstream errorFile("Resultsfor_Error.csv", std::ios_base::app);
      errorFile << "Error creating/opening output CSV file." << std::endl;
      return;
  }

  try {
      // Establish database connection and execute query
      SQLHENV hEnv;
      SQLHDBC hDbc;
      SQLRETURN retcode;

      // Allocate environment handle
      retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Error allocating environment handle.");
      }

      // Set the ODBC version environment attribute
      retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
          throw std::runtime_error("Error setting ODBC version attribute.");
      }

      // Allocate connection handle
      retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
          throw std::runtime_error("Error allocating connection handle.");
      }

      // Connect to the database
      retcode = SQLDriverConnectA(hDbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)data.connectionString.c_str(), SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
          throw std::runtime_error("Error connecting to the database.");
      }

      // Execute the query
      SQLHSTMT hStmt;
      retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
          throw std::runtime_error("Error allocating statement handle.");
      }

      retcode = SQLExecDirectA(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)data.query.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);
          SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
          SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
          throw std::runtime_error("Error executing query.");
      }

      // Process the query results
      SQLSMALLINT numCols;
      retcode = SQLNumResultCols(hStmt, &numCols);
      if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Error retrieving the number of result columns.");
      }

      // Write header
      for (SQLSMALLINT i = 1; i <= numCols; ++i) {
          SQLCHAR colName[256];
          SQLSMALLINT colNameLength;
          retcode = SQLDescribeColA(hStmt, i, colName, sizeof(colName),    &colNameLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
          if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
              outputFile << "Error describing column: " << i << std::endl;
              continue;
          }
          outputFile << colName;
          if (i < numCols) {
              outputFile << ",";
          }
      }
      outputFile << std::endl;

I've confirmed that the creds i have are correct because I am able to connect and pull data via excel. I've tried different versions of the connections string including the DBQ and others

Unrelated (maybe), but instead of making up your own error messages, your application should be calling SQLGetDiagRec when errors occur.  From the comments section at the link: An application typically calls SQLGetDiagRec when a previous call to an ODBC function has returned SQL_ERROR or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO.
